# Rails 2, move a column of data to a new table & remove the column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in Rails version 2 (working on legacy project).

I have already a `students` table which has a column `course` that’s `varchar(255)` type:

```
mysql> describe students;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| course         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| age            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Now, I would like to refactor it so that each `student` can have many courses. So, I firstly created a migration file to create `courses` table:

```
class CreateCourse < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
      create_table :courses do |t|
          t.timestamps
          t.string :name, :null => false
          t.references :student, :null => false
      end
      add_index :courses, :student_id
  end

  def self.down
      drop_table :courses
  end
end
```

I run migration, the `courses` table is created successfully.

In student.rb I also declared:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end
```

In newly created course.rb I also have:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
end
```

Now, I think I need to do two things:

1. I need to remove the `course varchar(255)` column from `students`' table, because it is not needed anymore. I guess I just write another DB migration should do it.
2. Move the old data to new `courses` table. That's I need to move the data data in previous `course varchar(255)` column of `students` table to the newly created `courses` table's `name` column & fill with corresponding student_id to the `courses` table.  How to do that?

(Also pleases correct me if I am wrong above. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you first have to do **number 2**, and then **number 1** or you will lose your data.

You can make number 2 in the Rails console:

```
Student.all.each do |student|
  student.courses.create!(name: student.course)
end
```

It may take a while if your database is too big. After this process has completed, you may erase the column `course` from `students`.

Try this in SQL:

```
def self.up
  execute <<-SQL
    INSERT INTO courses(name, student_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT s.course, s.id
    FROM students AS s
  SQL
end
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do number 2 with database migration?

Comment: Thanks, what about ```down``` part of the migration so that I could rollback if something wrong?

Comment: That would require to write into each `student`, the correct `course.name` in the column `student.course`, where `student.id = course.student_id`. I'm not sure how to write that in SQL and would rather not give you an incomplete/dangerous proposal.

Comment: Thanks, be sure to update it if you find exactly that `def self.down` version of this query so that anyone can see the complete solution. Happy coding.